# Pentaho - Kettle - Job roda no spoon, más não roda no kitchen

Tags: pentaho

Tenho um *job* simples que simplesmente roda uma transformação que conecta no banco de dados Oracle via jdbc, faz um *select* por um *database* *input* e grava os dados em uma outra tabela.
Acontece que no Spoon ele roda sem problemas, mas no kitchen ele roda, mas não grava os dados no banco e não dá nenhum erro.
Segue a mensagem do kitchen que mesmo em Rowlevel está trazendo um *log* pequeno e não insere os dados.

Log do Kitchen

> DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe 2015/06/30 15:49:15 - Kitchen -
>   Logging is at level : Rowlevel (very detailed) 2015/06/30 15:49:15 -
>   Kitchen - Start of run. 2015/06/30 15:49:15 - Kitchen - Allocate new
>   job. 2015/06/30 15:49:15 - Kitchen - Parsing command line options.
>   2015/06/30 15:49:18 - Job-Dimensoes - Start of job execution
>   2015/06/30 15:49:18 - Job-Dimensoes - exec(0, 0, START.0) 2015/06/30
>   15:49:18 - START - Starting job entry 2015/06/30 15:49:18 -
>   Job-Dimensoes - Starting entry [DI_EMPRESA] 2015/06/30 15:49:18 -
>   Job-Dimensoes - exec(1, 0, DI_EMPRESA.0) 2015/06/30 15:49:18 -
>   DI_EMPRESA - Starting job entry 2015/06/30 15:49:18 - DI_EMPRESA -
>   Opening transformation: [null] in directory [/] 2015/06/30 15:49:18 -
>   DI_EMPRESA - Loading transformation from repository [DI_EMPRESA] in
>   directory [/] 2015/06/30 15:49:18 - Kitchen - Finished! 2015/06/30
>   15:49:18 - Kitchen - Start=2015/06/30 15:49:15.332, Stop=2015/06/30
>   15:49:18.129 2015/06/30 15:49:18 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 2
>   seconds.

Log do Spoon

> 2015/06/30 15:57:45 - Spoon - Starting job... 2015/06/30 15:57:45 -
>   Job-Dimensoes - Start of job execution 2015/06/30 15:57:45 -
>   Job-Dimensoes - exec(0, 0, START.0) 2015/06/30 15:57:45 - START -
>   Starting job entry 2015/06/30 15:57:45 - Job-Dimensoes - Starting
>   entry [DI_EMPRESA] 2015/06/30 15:57:45 - Job-Dimensoes - exec(1, 0,
>   DI_EMPRESA.0) 2015/06/30 15:57:45 - DI_EMPRESA - Starting job entry
>   2015/06/30 15:57:45 - DI_EMPRESA - Opening transformation: [null] in
>   directory [/] 2015/06/30 15:57:45 - DI_EMPRESA - Loading
>   transformation from repository [DI_EMPRESA] in directory [/]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - Starting
>   transformation...(file=null, name=DI_EMPRESA, repinfo=null) 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - Transformation is pre-loaded. 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - nr of steps to run : 3  , nr of hops : 2
>   2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - Dispatching started for
>   transformation [DI_EMPRESA] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - Nr of
>   arguments detected:10 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - This is not a
>   replay transformation 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - I found 3
>   different steps to launch. 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -
>   Allocating rowsets... 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Allocating
>   rowsets for step 0 --> Add sequence 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -
>   prevcopies = 1, nextcopies=1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -
>   Transformation allocated new rowset [Add sequence.0 - Insert /
>   Update.0] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Allocated 1 rowsets for
>   step 0 --> Add sequence 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Allocating
>   rowsets for step 1 --> Insert / Update 2015/06/30 15:57:46 -
>   DI_EMPRESA -  Allocated 1 rowsets for step 1 --> Insert / Update
>   2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Allocating rowsets for step 2 -->
>   Table input 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -   prevcopies = 1,
>   nextcopies=1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - Transformation
>   allocated new rowset [Table input.0 - Add sequence.0] 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Allocated 2 rowsets for step 2 --> Table
>   input 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - Allocating Steps &
>   StepData... 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Transformation is
>   about to allocate step [Add sequence] of type [Sequence] 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -   Step has nrcopies=1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 -
>   Add sequence.0 - distribution activated 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add
>   sequence.0 - Starting allocation of buffers & new threads...
>   2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 - Step info: nrinput=1 nroutput=1
>   2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 - Got previous step from [Add
>   sequence] #0 --> Table input 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 -
>   input rel is 1:1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 - Found input
>   rowset [Table input.0 - Add sequence.0] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add
>   sequence.0 - output rel. is  1:1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0
>   - Found output rowset [Add sequence.0 - Insert / Update.0] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 - Finished dispatching 2015/06/30 15:57:46 -
>   DI_EMPRESA -  Transformation has allocated a new step: [Add
>   sequence].0 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Transformation is
>   about to allocate step [Insert / Update] of type [InsertUpdate]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -   Step has nrcopies=1 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - distribution activated 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - Starting allocation of buffers & new
>   threads... 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - Step info:
>   nrinput=1 nroutput=0 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - Got
>   previous step from [Insert / Update] #0 --> Add sequence 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - input rel is 1:1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 -
>   Insert / Update.0 - Found input rowset [Add sequence.0 - Insert /
>   Update.0] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - Finished
>   dispatching 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -  Transformation has
>   allocated a new step: [Insert / Update].0 2015/06/30 15:57:46 -
>   DI_EMPRESA -  Transformation is about to allocate step [Table input]
>   of type [TableInput] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -   Step has
>   nrcopies=1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table input.0 - distribution
>   activated 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table input.0 - Starting allocation of
>   buffers & new threads... 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table input.0 - Step
>   info: nrinput=0 nroutput=1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table input.0 -
>   output rel. is  1:1 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table input.0 - Found output
>   rowset [Table input.0 - Add sequence.0] 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table
>   input.0 - Finished dispatching 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - 
>   Transformation has allocated a new step: [Table input].0 2015/06/30
>   15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA - This transformation can be replayed with
>   replay date: 2015/06/30 15:57:46 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - DI_EMPRESA -
>   Initialising 3 steps... 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 - Running
>   on slave server #0/1. 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Table input.0 - Running on
>   slave server #0/1. 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Insert / Update.0 - Running
>   on slave server #0/1. 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - pims_local - New database
>   connection defined 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - conn_local - New database
>   connection defined 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - conn_local - New database
>   connection defined 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - conn_local - Connected to
>   database. 2015/06/30 15:57:46 - Add sequence.0 - Connected to
>   database... 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - pims_local - Connected to database.
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - conn_local - Connected to database. 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - pims_local - Auto commit off 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   conn_local - Auto commit off 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0 -
>   Connected to database... 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - DI_EMPRESA - Step [Add
>   sequence.0] initialized flawlessly. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - DI_EMPRESA -
>   Step [Insert / Update.0] initialized flawlessly. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   DI_EMPRESA - Step [Table input.0] initialized flawlessly. 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - DI_EMPRESA - Transformation has allocated 3 threads and 2
>   rowsets. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Starting to run...
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Starting to run...
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0 - Starting to run... 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - Table input.0 - SQL query : SELECT  DISTINCT
>   NVL(CD_EMPRESA,-1) AS CD_EMPRESA,  NVL(DE_EMPRESA, 'DESCONHECIDO') AS
>   DS_EMPRESA, F_GET_GRUPOCLIENTE AS SK_GRUPOCLIENTE  2015/06/30 15:57:49
>   - Table input.0 - FROM EMPRESAS 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0 - UNION 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0 - SELECT  '-1' , 
>   'DESCONHECIDO' , F_GET_GRUPOCLIENTE  2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table
>   input.0 - FROM DUAL 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0 - ORDER BY 1
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #1 : [0],
>   [CONSOLIDADORA], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0 - Signaling
>   'output done' to 1 output rowsets. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Table input.0
>   - Finished reading query, closing connection. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - pims_local - Commit on database connection [pims_local] 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #1 : [0], [CONSOLIDADORA], [2]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #2 : [-1],
>   [DESCONHECIDO], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Checking
>   row: [0], [CONSOLIDADORA], [2], [56] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert /
>   Update.0 - Field [CD_EMPRESA] has nr. 0 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert /
>   Update.0 - Field [SK_GRUPOCLIENTE] has nr. 2 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   Insert / Update.0 - Field [CD_EMPRESA] has nr. 0 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #2 : [-1], [DESCONHECIDO], [2] 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Field [DS_EMPRESA] has nr. 1 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #3 : [1], [Cliente - Unidade 2.],
>   [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Field [SK_GRUPOCLIENTE]
>   has nr. 2 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Field [SK_EMPRESA]
>   has nr. 3 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Setting
>   preparedStatement to [SELECT CD_EMPRESA, DS_EMPRESA, SK_GRUPOCLIENTE,
>   SK_EMPRESA FROM DI_EMPRESA WHERE  ( ( CD_EMPRESA = ?  ) )  AND  ( (
>   SK_GRUPOCLIENTE = ?  ) ) ] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - conn_local -
>   Preparing statement:  2015/06/30 15:57:49 - conn_local - INSERT INTO
>   DI_EMPRESA (CD_EMPRESA, DS_EMPRESA, SK_GRUPOCLIENTE, SK_EMPRESA)
>   VALUES ( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?) 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 -
>   Setting update preparedStatement to [UPDATE DI_EMPRESA 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - SET DS_EMPRESA = ? 2015/06/30 15:57:49
>   - Insert / Update.0 - WHERE  ( ( CD_EMPRESA = ?  ) ) AND    ( ( SK_GRUPOCLIENTE = ?  ) ) ] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 -
>   Values set for lookup: [0], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 -
>   Wrote row #3 : [1], [Cliente - Unidade 2.], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   pims_local - Connection to database closed! 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add
>   sequence.0 - Read row #4 : [10], [Unidade y], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49
>   - Table input.0 - Finished processing (I=11, O=0, R=0, W=11, U=0, E=0) 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #4 : [10], [Unidade
>   y], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #5 : [2],
>   [Cliente -  Unidade 1], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 -
>   Insert row: ![0], [CONSOLIDADORA], [2], [56] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add
>   sequence.0 - Wrote row #5 : [2], [Cliente -  Unidade 1], [2]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #6 : [3], [Cliente -
>   Unidade 3], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set
>   for lookup: [-1], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row
>
> ## 6 : [3], [Cliente - Unidade 3], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #7 : [4], [Cliente -Unidade 4], [2] 2015/06/30
>
> 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![-1], [DESCONHECIDO], [2],
>   [57] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #7 : [4],
>   [Cliente -Unidade 4], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read
>   row #8 : [5], [Unidade x], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 -
>   Wrote row #8 : [5], [Unidade x], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add
>   sequence.0 - Read row #9 : [6], [Usina Unidade 1 Ltda.], [2]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set for lookup: [1],
>   [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #9 : [6], [Usina
>   Unidade 1 Ltda.], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row
>
> ## 10 : [7], [Unidade y], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![1], [Cliente - Unidade 2.], [2], [58] 2015/06/30
>
> 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #10 : [7], [Unidade y], [2]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Read row #11 : [8], [Unidade
>   y], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set for
>   lookup: [10], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Wrote row #11
>   : [8], [Unidade y], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 -
>   Signaling 'output done' to 1 output rowsets. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![10], [Unidade y], [2], [59]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set for lookup: [2],
>   [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - conn_local - Connection to database closed!
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Add sequence.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0,
>   R=11, W=11, U=0, E=0) 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert
>   row: ![2], [Cliente -  Unidade 1], [2], [60] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   Insert / Update.0 - Values set for lookup: [3], [2] 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![3], [Cliente - Unidade
>   3], [2], [61] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set for
>   lookup: [4], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert row:
>   ![4], [Cliente -Unidade 4], [2], [62] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert /
>   Update.0 - Values set for lookup: [5], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![5], [Agropecuaria Goitá Grande],
>   [2], [63] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set for
>   lookup: [6], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert row:
>   ![6], [Usina Unidade 1 Ltda.], [2], [64] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert
>   / Update.0 - Values set for lookup: [7], [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![7], [Unidade y], [2], [65]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Values set for lookup: [8],
>   [2] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Insert row: ![8],
>   [Unidade y], [2], [66] 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 -
>   Signaling 'output done' to 0 output rowsets. 2015/06/30 15:57:49 -
>   conn_local - Commit on database connection [conn_local] 2015/06/30
>   15:57:49 - conn_local - Commit on database connection [conn_local]
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - conn_local - Connection to database closed!
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Insert / Update.0 - Finished processing (I=11,
>   O=11, R=11, W=11, U=0, E=0) 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Job-Dimensoes -
>   Starting entry [10_Carrega_stage.SUCCESS.staging] 2015/06/30 15:57:49
>   - Job-Dimensoes - exec(2, 0, 10_Carrega_stage.SUCCESS.staging.0) 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - 10_Carrega_stage.SUCCESS.staging - Starting job
>   entry 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Job-Dimensoes - Finished job entry
>   [10_Carrega_stage.SUCCESS.staging] (result=[true]) 2015/06/30 15:57:49
>   - Job-Dimensoes - Finished job entry [DI_EMPRESA] (result=[true]) 2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Job-Dimensoes - Job execution finished
>   2015/06/30 15:57:49 - Spoon - Job has ended.

Alguém já teve algum problema parecido?